# If else statement syntax issue in PHP class

Tags: php, class, if-statement

I am making a class to check for holidays. I made functions for specific holidays and an overarching function to see if a date is a holiday, not one in particular.

I am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgmt\classes\Holidays.php on line 52
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Holidays {

    //private member variables
    private $date;

    //constructors
    public function Holidays() {
        $this->$date = date("Y-m-d");
    }

    //setters
    public function setDate($date) {
        $this->$date = $date;
    }

    //getters
    public function getDate() {
        return $this->$date;
    }

    //member public functions
    public function isNewYears($date) {
        return ($date == date('Y', $date)."-01-01" ? true : false);
    }
    public function isMLKDay($date) {
        return ($date == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("third Monday of January ".date('Y', $date)) ? true : false));
    }
    public function isValentinesDay($date) {
        return ($date == date('Y', $date)."-02-14" ? true : false);
    }
    public function isPresidentsDay($date) {
        return ($date == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("third Monday of February ".date('Y', $date)) ? true : false));
    }
    public function isEaster($date) {
        return ($date == date("Y-m-d", easter_date($date)) ? true : false);
    }
    public function isMemorialDay($date) {
        return ($date == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Monday of May ".date('Y', $date)) ? true : false));
    }
    public function isLaborDay($date) {
        return ($date == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first Monday of September ".date('Y', $date)) ? true : false));
    }
    public function isThanksgiving($date) {
        return ($date == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("fourth Thursday in November".date('Y', $date)) ? true : false));
    }
    public function isChristmas($date) {
        return ($date == date('Y', $date)."-12-25" ? true : false);
    }   
    public function isHoliday($date) {
        if (isNewYears($date))
        else if (isMLKDay($date))
        else if (isValentinesDay($date))
        else if (isPresidentsDay($date))
        else if (isEaster($date))
        else if (isMemorialDay($date))
        else if (isLaborDay($date))
        else if (isThanksgiving($date))
        else if (isChristmas($date))
        else return false;
    }
}
?>
```

It's throwing the error on the first else statement in `isHoliday()`. If that's not the proper structure then how should I do it?

Comment: PHP thinks your `else if` statements have no bodies - and they don't. For clarify (and avoiding syntactic pitfalls) you should always use braces with `if` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do a logical or, which can be represented using `||`

```
public function isHoliday($date) {
    return $this->isNewYears($date)
        || $this->isMLKDay($date)
        || $this->isValentinesDay($date)
        || $this->isPresidentsDay($date)
        || $this->isEaster($date)
        || $this->isMemorialDay($date)
        || $this->isLaborDay($date)
        || $this->isThanksgiving($date)
        || $this->isChristmas($date);
}
```

You can also remove the if/else, and simply return the result of the boolean expression itself.

Edit - 
There are additional errors with your posted code -

Constructor should use $this->date, not $this->$date

```
public function Holidays() {
    $this->date = date("Y-m-d");
}
```

Further to the above, if you ever need the current instantiated value of $date, then you should use the notation

```
 $this->date
```

The function easter_date does not exist

```
public function isEaster($date) {
    return ($date == date("Y-m-d", easter_date($date)) ? true : false);
}
```

After you have fixed this issues, you should be able to use it as -

```
$holidays = new Holidays();
$isHoliday = $holidays->isHoliday(date("Y-m-d"));
if($isHoliday) {
  echo "Today is a holiday!";
} else {
  echo "Today is not a holiday! :(";
}
```

As your functions all seem to be helpers, it might be suggested to look at static functions in php instead :)

Comment: This is probably a good tip but it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Got this error: `atal error: Call to undefined function isNewYears() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgmt\classes\Holidays.php on line 51`

Comment: Apologies, forgot the prefix of `$this->` to function calls

Comment: I have added some additional comments about further issues I have noticed, hopefully it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on why they should be static? I am really unfamiliar with them. I read a couple of articles but am still not really getting it.

Comment: Your functions are 'helpers', IE it does not make sense for it to be associated with an instance of a class. For that kind of function, static functions are used. There will be a lot of resources available for this within the php docs

Answer (score 1):

You kind of need a statement to execute when the `if` passes...

```
if( isNewYears($date)) do_something_here();
else...
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a suitable answer, as there is nothing useful that could be done within the expression blocks other than 'return true'

Comment: Yours is the correct answer, @AlanFoster. I will mark it as such when StackOverflow allows.

Comment: The answer is "half correct" -- the solution is not to add something to be executed there... but to add a semicolon after the if which means nothing needs to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Disregard my answer. Alan Foster's is better and should be the accepted answer IMO.**
Try:

```
public function isHoliday($date) {
    $this->date = $date;
    if (
        $this->date->isNewYears($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isMLKDay($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isValentinesDay($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isPresidentsDay($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isEaster($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isMemorialDay($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isLaborDay($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isThanksgiving($date)
        ||
        $this->date->isChristmas($date)
    ) 
    { 
        return true; 
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on `$this->$date` for me? I was under the impression `this` meant the variable passed in. It seems as though in PHP it refers to the class member variable?

Comment: I am going to remove my answer as AlanFoster's is actually correct, since the functions return booleans already. $this->date is an alias of $date, but only available inside the function unless you call it at the top of the class, like `public $date = NULL;` would let you pass the same date to any function(as $this->date)

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the error. If you don't need any code, leave it like this, otherwise in specific sections you can write your code:

```
public function isHoliday($date) {
    if (isNewYears($date)) {}
    else if (isMLKDay($date)) {}
    else if (isValentinesDay($date)) {}
    else if (isPresidentsDay($date)) {}
    else if (isEaster($date)) {}
    else if (isMemorialDay($date)) {}
    else if (isLaborDay($date)) {}
    else if (isThanksgiving($date)) {}
    else if (isChristmas($date)) {}
    else return false;
}
```